# count number of rows needed to have sum greater than a particular value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to subset dataframe such that no of rows needed to get `mpg` value is at least 100.

```
library(datasets)

data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

The output should be top 5 values
here mpg sum is >100 after Hornet Sportabout

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

I want to the checksum at each row for the mpg column and then the output as no of rows it took to get that sum of at least 100

Comment: I think the `while` statement is what you are looking for https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/while-loop/

Comment: Thanks. I want it to the checksum of all the above rows of mpg column after each step and then the output as no of rows it took to get that sum of at least 100.

Comment: can you provide a reprex?

Comment: @Bruno i have updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

I would use `cumsum` in association with `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
    
mtcars %>% 
      filter(cumsum(lag(mpg, default = 0)) < 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it

```
library(tidyverse)


df_answer <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(cum_sum = cumsum(mpg)) %>% 
  filter(cum_sum < 100)

df_answer %>% 
  nrow() + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `subset` + `cumsum`

```
subset(mtcars, c(TRUE, cumsum(mpg) <= 100)[-nrow(mtcars)])
```

gives

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `purrr` library:

```
library(purrr)
which.max(purrr::accumulate(mtcars$mpg, `+`) > 100)

# 5
```

---

If you want the whole dataset you can use `dplyr::slice`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dplyr::slice(mtcars, 1 : which.max(purrr::accumulate(mtcars$mpg, `+`) > 100))

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter condition with `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% 1:(max(which(cumsum(mpg) < 100)) + 1))
```

> ```
>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
> ```

The code can be shortened with `slice`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  slice(1:(max(which(cumsum(mpg) < 100)) + 1))
```

And packaged as a function:

```r
fnc = function(data, var, cutoff) {
  data %>% 
    slice(1:(max(which(cumsum({{var}}) < cutoff)) + 1))
}
```

```
fnc(mtcars, mpg, 100)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2

fnc(iris, Sepal.Width, 10)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
```